Dynamic width for autoGroupColumnDef in ag-grid
I am rendering grid in tree data mode and the first column is autoGridColumnDef. I want to provide dynmaic width to this particular column only. other columns are numeric columns and their width is given as 100.
adaptable grid version 17.0.6
ag-grid version 30.2.1
gridOptions = {
        autoGroupColumnDef = {
        "field": "name",
        "headerName": "Financial Statement",
        "width": 200,
        "pinned": "left",
        "filter": "agSetColumnFilter"
        floatingFilter: false,
        cellRendererParams: {
          suppressCount: true,
        }
      }
        treeData: true, // enable Tree Data mode
        getDataPath: data => {
          return data.name
        },
        getRowStyle: (params) => {
          if (params.data.class==='level1') {
            return { background: '#d7d8e9' };
          }
        },
      }


I tried following solutions but none of them worked for me-

in autoGroupColumnDef giving minWidth and maxWidth instead of width
minWidth:200,
maxWidth:400,

in autoGroupColumnDef giving flex instead of width
'flex':1,

in gridOptions added the following object-
autoSizeStrategy: {
type: 'fitCellContents'
},


am I missing something or doing something wrong?
